# IE 10 issue with JQuery, works after selecting different program window and going back

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-10

So I have a weird issue in IE 10: I open a JQuery dialog with a drop down and a textbox.

I am opening the dialog in an enter jquery event on the page that opens the dialog window.
My issue does NOT happen when it is the shift event though the code called is the same.

When opened with enter though the drop down list will close as soon as you click it, the mask on the textbox is not showing its graphics and if I select the textbox and press tab the focus keeps snapping back to the textbox.

HOWEVER when I select another program and then IE again, while in the dialog, it starts to work normally again...

When I turned off the mask (jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min.js) instead I could not tab away from the drop down list and still could not use clicks on it.

Also without the mask switching to another program and back did not help.

All my code works exactly as it should in FF and Chrome. Also its all normal JQ (Version 1.9.1 and the ui version 1.10.1) except the mask.

Weirdest thing I have seen yet with IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by moving focus to another field before opening the dialog. No idea why.